# Allow MySQL connections only from local machine

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I restrict my MySQL instance to only allow connections from my local machine?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? The answer is very different based on this.

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2005? I don't think it was SQL Server 5 since Sybase sold it, many, many, many moons ago.

Comment: sorry my worng :(

Mysql 5.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL permissions are done by user. To grant privileges to a user from an IP, you would do:

```
grant all on yourdb.* to user@127.0.0.1 identified by 'password'
```

You need to have created a user to use with this, first, though. Read more about MySQL user management [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-account-management.html).

Also, if you close your firewall on port 3306 to disallow incoming connections, that will also block them at the OS level.

Comment: tnx dude but can you explame me how to do that with firewall on win 2008 because i never have do it , now i try but dont see how to do

Comment: @BobiDesi - If you have it turned on, 3306 should be blocked by default. You will want to ask over at http://serverfault.com to get detailed instructions about the firewall. They know much better than I do, and I don't want to lead you astray.